# setMaxDate and setMinDate in MaterialCalendarView

Tags: android, material-design, calendarview

Is there any way of seting a minDate and a maxDate in a MaterialCalendarView as it was possible with CalendarView?

```
calendarView.setMaxDate(lastDateInMillis);
calendarView.setMinDate(firstDateInMillis);
```

Comment: MaterialCalendarView? What is this? Doesnt looks like a view provided by google/android

Comment: it third party lib for calender

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean the Third-Party-Lib https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview then you can set it using

```
calendarView.state().edit()
  .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
  .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 4, 3))
  .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2016, 5, 12))
  .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.WEEKS)
  .commit();
```

You can see the reason in their Major Change in 1.4.0.

Its because the setters for the min and maximum date are not just simple setters. They are "states" which should be treated like that.